# if i don't know array will be have how many elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to give an example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ana 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] array = new int[9]; // create array that have "9" elements
        }

}
```

Above example's array have 9 elements but i want to create unlimited array.
If I want this when I'm writing PHP I write this code:

```
<?php 
 $example = array();
 $example[] = 15; // auto numbering. PHP don't want number of array's element.
 $example[] = 20;
?>
```

And what does mean?

```
Auto[] array = {new Auto()};
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (such as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)). Java has a number of collections (List, Set, Map, Queue, etc.), with various implementations. Learn how to use them by reading the [collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different data structure, like a `Vector`.

Comment: Come on. ArrayList should be preferred over Vector since JDK 1.2. We're at JDK 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> as = new ArrayList<Integer>();
as.add(15);
as.add(20);
```

and `Auto[] array = {new Auto()};` is a Array of Type Auto with one element.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), resizable-array implementation of the List interface in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in java.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```